# Creating a table in postgres heroku

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, rack

i'm a ruby new bie.I'm trying to create a simple API using `rack` that takes a json data and writes that to the postgres heroku database table.
i created a database on postgres heroku, but didn't find out any option to create a table there.
Can any one provide some pointers to some good tutorials which explain how to go about accomplishing this.

Comment: Why not connect to the database and send it a bit of `CREATE TABLE` SQL?

Comment: ok in dat case every time i need to check if a table already exists before CREATE TABLE SQL

Comment: Or have a set up rake task that creates your tables and run that when you publish your application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a dev or basic plan, you won't be able to connect directly to the DB and manually create the table, so you will need to write a migration script that will create the table for you.

Using an ORM like ActiveRecord is generally a good idea and it makes it very easy to automate all the SQL grunt work. Use the sinatra-activerecord (https://github.com/janko-m/sinatra-activerecord
) gem to get the rake helper tasks on your rack app. Just make sure that instead of using local sqlite3, you use `ENV[DATABASE_URL]` to point to your Heroku db.

Then run the local command `rake db:create_migration NAME=json_data` to make your migration file and then once you have created it, run the Heroku command `heroku run bundle exec rake db:migrate` to create all the tables and schemas you need.